# Simple file writing, but its not working

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have looked through some examples of how to write to a file in Java, and i thought i was doing it right.... apparently not. what is wrong here, it isn't even creating a file to write to. no error, just not writing to the file.

```
File inputFile = new File("pa2Data.txt");
File outputFile = new File("pa2output.txt");
Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(inputFile);
BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

while(fileIn.hasNext()){
    String theLine = readFile(fileIn);
    fout.write("Infix expression: " + theLine + '\n');
    postfixExpression = infixToPostFix(theLine);
    String op = postfixExpression.toString();
    fout.write("Postfix Expression: " + op + '\n');

    theLine = readFile(fileIn);
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(theLine);
    for(int i = 0; i < theValues.length; i++)
        theValues[i]  = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        int answer = postfixEval(postfixExpression, theValues);
        fout.write("Answer: " + answer + '\n' + '\n'); 
    }
    fileIn.close();
    fout.close();

}//end main
```

Comment: try following this example http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/

Comment: The error you're seeing is...? http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Have you tried flushing it?

Comment: How are you handling the IOException that is possible from any of the streams?  I don't see a try catch block.  Are you seeing any errors?  What output do you see, any, nothing?

Comment: We are not seeing the complete picture here.... what is the method `readFile(...)` doing?

Comment: @StefanFreitag the rest of the code works when printed to the screen. the readFile just reads a line of data. the whole code is pretty long, i didn't want to post a wall of code.

Comment: @StillLearningToCode, I revised my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced your code to a working example from which you can continue...

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
      File inputFile = new File("pa2Data.txt");
      File outputFile = new File("pa2output.txt");
      Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(inputFile);
      BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

      while(fileIn.hasNext()){
        String theLine = fileIn.next();
        fout.write("Infix expression: " + theLine + '\n');
      }
      fileIn.close();
      fout.close();
   } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

}

Note that I have changed `readFile(fileIn); to` fileIn.next();`to read from the Scanner. Did so, because you used`hasNext()` in the condition of the while-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Java won't write to file when you use `write`, it will store all the data you want to write at the buffer untill you will `flush` or `close` it.
In your case, a `flush` will be advised, because you writting to the file and reading it for changes, that results in reading data before you wrote the new data in.

You will need to use `flush` before reading the file.
That means before `theLine = readFile(fileIn);`

Comment: Not usually.  Flushing automatically happens when the stream is closed.

Comment: thanks for the input. i tried to use flush() but no change. shouldn't the line 'File outputFile = new File("pa2output.txt");' create a file in the directory?

Comment: @StillLearningToCode, I meant, `fout.flush();`